# How to swith next actitvity onItemselect according to url?

Tags: android

```
if(txt2[i]!=null)
    {
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Lucenconcept.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,txt2));   
    }

 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {   
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
         AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(ListviewOnclickExample.this);
         adb.setTitle("LVSelectedItemExample");
         adb.setMessage("Selected Item is = "+lv1.getItemAtPosition(position));
         adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
         adb.show();
         }   
    });
```

I m able to display data on list view i h have string of url also i want to go next activity on item select on particular path selection it telling some Error on OnItemClickListener cannot resolved plz fix this issue how to fix..

Comment: What is the Error? Also what's your activity name?

Comment: Look at this tutorial [Android: How to switch between Activities](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/). and try to understand how activity switches..

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna move next activity then

```
Intent intent = new Intent(yourCurrentActivity.this,whereYouWantToGoActivity.Class);
startActivity(intent);
```

hope this will helps you...